# Solutions for grouping and managing many different in-memory indexes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, indexing, grouping

I have a list of Person objects, currently I use 5 different instances of associative structures (std::map/multimap, std::unordered_map) to provide efficient queries for various kinds of static results, eg: all people within the age range of 20-40, or all people with a first name of john etc..

As the Person struct evolves, I find I have to deal with manually adding a new type of index, figuring out what the correct structure for it should be, etc and in short its getting very unmanageable.

In the future it seems that the queries are going to get more and more complicated. - We've gone down the DB/SQL approach, it is simple too slow for our needs, at the moment the current solution is fast enough, but it is becoming very unmanageable from a software engineering perspective.

My question is, are there any libraries or solutions that provide collective indexes (in-memory) for a list of objects in a manageable manner?

Comment: Have you tried [Boost multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Would [Boost.Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) be of help?

Comment: I didn't know about that, looking at it now, it seems to be exactly what i was looking for, now i have to get my head around the metaprogramming concepts.